# overpass: some issue with wrong order of points to make polygon

Tags: polygon, overpass-api

I am running this query on overpass-turbo

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
rel(223133);
(
  rel(r);
);
rel(1250951);

out geom;
```

and I have received this polygon.

[image]

but when I process this data my Image is like this :

[image]

I am using dot net core and this is my query

```
foreach (var m in geoElement.members)
{
    if (m is { type: "way", role: "outer" })
    {
        foreach (var g in m.geometry)
        {
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(g.lon, g.lat);
            coordinates.Add(coordinate);
        }
    }

}
var shell = new LinearRing(coordinates.ToArray());

var p = new Polygon(shell);
        var serializer = GeoJsonSerializer.Create();
        using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

        serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, p);
        var geoJson = stringWriter.ToString();
        return geoJson;
```

First I added all geometries lat and lng into a coordinate list and finally, I make a polygon and at the end I make a GeoJSON.

What tips exist here?

I downloaded GeoJSON file from Overpass and I checked with my made GeoJSON. there is so different from points. I don't know why. How can I make GeoJSON like an overpass downloaded file?

This is my GeoJson file I made from Rwa data: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DSgkSf7qnH/

Comment: I downloaded the same polygon. The geometry part looks like: `"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              33.0320818,
              38.1524781
            ],
            [
              33.0264817,
              38.143384
            ],` - see screenshot of the GeoJSON: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfgee.png

Comment: I don't understand what is your point, I downloaded GeoJson but so different when we run my query and make a polygon. I want to make GeoJson from raw data by running query@Babel

Comment: As you can see I made a polygon but my polygon has a problem. do you know is there the any tips to make polygon from Row data by running overpass query @Babel

Comment: So it seems I don't understand your point - your question is not about how to create a GeoJSON file? Than you could simply imitate the structure of the downloaded file. If not, than your question is confusing an I'm not sure what you want to ask.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information. How could we know what is the problem in your case if you don't provide the information where you have the points from that you use to generate the polygon? So you try to make this polygon yourself? Or you need downloaded data?

Comment: Not sure: why don't you download simply the polygon from Overpass? As it looks, you connect the points in the wrong order.

Comment: Imagin that for a few countries I have to download polygons for their state and all cities inside those states (provinces) and finally save all data into Postgres. and from front I need to these information It is so difficult  @Babel

Comment: My problem is: from my API I call overpass-turbo with that query and I received the response and by that code I have sent I make a polygon. In qgis I added my polygon as you can see, there is a problem .I don't know what is the problem bro @Babel

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. What I understand: you download points and want to connect them to create a polygon - even if the date already exists as a polygon. If you want to connect them manually, make sure to have the correct order. This is not the case in the file you provided. E.g. form vertex 0 to 17, everything is correct, afterwards, it's quite a mess.

Comment: Why don't you download your data as polygon? No need to create it yourself.

Comment: How can I do that? download as a polygon? I don't know if it is possible. I just know from overpass site w can download data but I want to download from my API and store into my databas @Babel

Comment: Export > GeoJSON > download, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXaPV.png

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to do it manually. I want to when from the front application calls a Api method, this thing happened automatically @Babel

Comment: Does it help to replace `out geom;` with `>;
out skel qt;` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xBZrtzjVqn/ there is no geom .@Babel

Comment: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1upu this is query @Babel

Comment: Hm, not sure. If your final task is to download a lot of data from OpenStreetMap and to import it to PostGIS, did you consider downloading data e.g. from Geofabrik?

Comment: I wondered, what tips are to create the correct polygon from Raw data!!! @Babel